# How do I do if ?currency exists show x else show y

Tags: php

I want the user to see this if ?currency= isn't in the url:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h2>Modules</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content-inner" style="text-align:center">
            <form action="client.php" method="get" target="_blank">
                Currency:<br><input type="text" name="Currency"><br>
                <div class="list-block inset">
                    <input class="inset button button-round active" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the user to see this if ?currency= is in the url:

```
<div class="list-block">
    <ul>
        <li class="item-content">
            <div class="item-media">
                <img src="https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/19633/<?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?>.png?width=200" height="50px" />
            </div>
            <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">
                    <?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="item-after">
                    <span class="badge" id="<?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?>" style="background-color: #000000;">Fetching...</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If a user is on http://ppyazi.com/pricepoint/client.php, **?currency=** isn't in the url.

If a user is is on http://ppyazi.com/pricepoint/client.php?currency=neo, **?currency=** is in the url.

Comment: `if (isset($_GET['currency'])) { //yes } else { //no }` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, how will I add the 3 things into the script as html

Comment: Do you know any PHP to start with? This page got some basic examples: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: I do know basic php

Comment: Then I don't get the question? Anyway, you can check the link I posted for more info..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your client.php you can use php like this:

```
<!-- any previeous HTML code -->

<?php if(isset($_GET['currency'])){ ?>
    <!-- currency is set in url, paste your html code here for that case -->
<?php } else { ?>
    <!-- currency is not set in url, paste your form here -->
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

```
    if ( isset($_GET['currency']) ) { 
        echo '<div class="list-block"><ul><li class="item-content"><div class="item-media"><img src="https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/19633/<?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?>.png?width=200" height="50px" /></div><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title"><?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?></div><div class="item-after"><span class="badge" id="<?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?>" style="background-color: #000000;">Fetching...</span></div></div></li></ul></div>';
     } else {
        echo '<div class="card"><div class="card-content"><div class="card-header"><h2>Modules</h2></div><div class="card-content-inner" style="text-align:center"><form action="client.php" method="get" target="_blank">Currency:<br><input type="text" name="Currency"><br><div class="list-block inset"><input class="inset button button-round active" type="submit" value="Submit"></div></form></div></div></div>';
     }
```

Comment: The neo was an example. I want it to be for any

Comment: I would recommend exiting PHP mode when outputting the HTML. It's better for syntax highlighting and debugging. Plus, you currently have `<?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?>` inside the first html block. That would be literally outputted as that.

Comment: what ur triying to tell Mr. @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 1):

Simply add condition to retrieve currency value with `$_GET`

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['currency']) && $_GET['currency'] != "")
{
?>
<div class="list-block"><ul><li class="item-content"><div class="item-media"><img src="https://www.cryptocompare.com/media/19633/<?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?>.png?width=200" height="50px" /></div><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title"><?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?></div><div class="item-after"><span class="badge" id="<?php echo $_GET["currency"]; ?>" style="background-color: #000000;">Fetching...</span></div></div></li></ul></div>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<div class="card"><div class="card-content"><div class="card-header"><h2>Modules</h2></div><div class="card-content-inner" style="text-align:center"><form action="client.php" method="get" target="_blank">Currency:<br><input type="text" name="Currency"><br><div class="list-block inset"><input class="inset button button-round active" type="submit" value="Submit"></div></form></div></div></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You could probably just use `empty($_GET['currency'])` instead of two checks in this snippet.